# CSS Child element vs descendant selector implementation issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn CSS and came across the concept of child selector and descendant selector. To try this out I implemented the following HTML code and linked with the given CSS code.

```css
ol>li {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>first main list item</li>
  <li>second main list item</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>first sub-list item</li>
      <li>second sub-list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

My expectation was only the main list items to become blueviolet as this has been defined as a child selector. I thought the child selector will only select direct child elements and ignore the second level child elements. But instead, all sub-child and main-child elements became blue violet. Is my understanding wrong about these two selector types?

Comment: As one of the answers points out, the `li` with the nested `ul` is still a first level direct child of the `ol` parent. And since you didn't assign any differing styles to the nested `ul li` elements, those will inherit the color of the parent element.

Comment: So i am assuming my understanding about "direct child" is not accurate. Because according to my understanding I though that direct child means the direct elements of a parenting element. In this case, according to my understanding, the <li> elements of <ul> are not direct child of the main parent <ol>. Looks like that understanding is incorrect. So if that is the case what is the definition for 'direct child' elements?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect because you are not thinking of how children elements inherit styles. You are styling the top level `li` tag **AND** every element in it because it is a direct child and you are not creating another rule that has more specificity for those children elements. If you look at Ankit's answer, that's how you need to be thinking about direct children.

Comment: if you apply `body{color:red}` all your elements will be red BUT you never selected any of them. Selector and inheritance are two different and orthogonal concepts that you need to understand independently

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All `<li>` tags in your 1st list element are direct children of your `<ol>` so they all will have a blueviolet background when you use the `ol > li` CSS selector

What you're trying to achieve can be achieved by overriding this style with `ol > li > ul > li` selector to get different styles for these nested `<li>` elements

Answer (score 0):

As you have putted `ul` inside child `li` tag of `ol` so whole are in `color: blueviolet;` . You have to put `ul` tag outside `li` tag or use a different approach for selector .  Refer to below snippet for some ways .

```css
ol>li {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.differ li>ul {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>How code is running</h1>
<ol>
  <li>first main list item</li>
  <li>second main list item</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>first sub-list item</li>
      <li>second sub-list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>

<h1>Solution Way 1</h1>
<ol>
  <li>first main list item</li>
  <li>second main list item</li>
  <ul>
    <li>first sub-list item</li>
    <li>second sub-list item</li>
  </ul>
</ol>

<h1>Solution Way 2</h1>
<ol class="differ">
  <li>first main list item</li>
  <li>second main list item</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>first sub-list item</li>
      <li>second sub-list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before it selects li with all it child elements as text-color is inherited by default. To prevent a 2nd level list to inherit the text-color by default you have to reset it by using `li > * { color: initial }`. This will reset the text-color to the default color while no inheriting the color from the parent `li` element.

```css
ol > li {
  color: blueviolet;
}

li > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>first main list item</li>
  <li>second main list item</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>first sub-list item</li>
      <li>second sub-list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```